# Sending information between users in a room in Photon

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I have followed the [PUN Basics Tutorial](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/intro) in order to create a lobby for my game and to connect two players. However, I am making a board game (Nine Men's Morris) and the tutorial only covers how to communicate by using an observer on the player character. I need to be able to send a move (where the player is moving from, where the player is moving to, which piece is the player removing) from one player to another.

Am I barking up the wrong tree by using Photon? I've searched and searched online but I am not finding much on this. Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

you told us that you already have two players connected to the same room, so I will begin at this point. The player who starts the game firstly wants to place one of his gaming pieces on the board, therefore I guess he directly clicks on the board to instantiate the object. When doing this using Photon you have to call PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(...) which will - obviously - instantiate the object across the network. The used prefab needs to have a PhotonView component and also a PhotonTransformView component, which is observed by the PhotonView. This will synchronize the moves later on and should be nothing new to you since you worked through the Basics Tutorial.

When all objects are instantiated the moving phase begins. Therefore you need some code which handles the player's input and moves the gaming piece from one position to another. Since you have attached and observed a PhotonTransformView component, the new position is automatically synchronized for all players.

This is a simple solution, you can also do this by using RaiseEvent(...) calls which is a slightly more advanced solution which might require some more work.

Since this is a turn based game, I would also recommend you taking a look at the RockPaperScissors Demo included in the PUN package and also the PunTurnManager script which might also help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it figured out.